# Run commands on host on 'docker-compose up'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to run specifics commands that would be automatically fired on `docker-compose up`

I want to avoid all those steps : https://github.com/FLKone/Dodee/tree/php_mysql_slim

(downloading a zip containing the docker-compose.yml + some required default file)

In that example I need a default config file for Nginx.

So now the solution is to download the zip containing both the yml and the config file. But it would be better if the config file was downloaded  when the user run `docker-compose up` (or created by it, to limit network access)

(Maybe the best practice here is to create an installion script to download both the yml and the config file ?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to run specifics commands that would be automatically fired on `docker-compose up`

Use [entrypoint](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#entrypoint) in your docker-compose.yml. You can do this per service, so the `web` container can download/configure nginx conf, the `php` container can run composer, etc.